# table cuts off page after 2nd <td>

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't know why but my table cuts off right after the second `<td>` tag... can anyone help, I have constantly looked over it over and over. Can someone help me find where the problem is?

```
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="username" type="text" value='<?
            if($form->value("username")==""){
                echo($req_user_info["username"]);
            }else{
                echo $form->value("username");
            }
        ?>' size="56" maxlength="30">
    </td>
    <td>
        <? echo($form->error("username")); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>New Password:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="newpass" type="password" value='<?
            echo($form->value("newpass"));
        ?>' size="56" maxlength="30">
    </td>
    <td>
        <? echo($form->error("newpass")); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Btw, that code is only the first two rows.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
<form action="adminprocess.php" method="POST">
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td>
    <input name="username" type="text" value='<?php
        if($form->value("username")==""){
            echo($req_user_info["username"]);
        }else{
            echo $form->value("username");
        }
    ?>' size="56" maxlength="30">
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo($form->error("username")); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>New Password:</td>
<td>
    <input name="newpass" type="password" value='<?php
        echo($form->value("newpass"));
    ?>' size="56" maxlength="30">
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo($form->error("newpass")); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm New Password:</td>
<td><input name="conf_newpass" type="password" value='
<?php echo $form->value("newpass"); ?>' size="56" maxlength="30"></td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("newpass"); ?></td>
</tr>
</tr>
<td>Edit motto:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="56" name="motto" value='<?php
if($form->value("motto") == ""){
echo $req_user_info['motto'];
}else{
echo $form->value("motto");
}
?>'></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Edit profile bio:</td>
<td><textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="profile" value=""><?php
if($form->value("profile") == ""){
echo $req_user_info['profile'];
}else{
echo $form->value("profile");
}
?></textarea></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" value='
<?php
if($form->value("email") == ""){
echo $req_user_info["email"];
}else{
echo $form->value("email");
}
?>' size="56" maxlength="50">
</td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("email"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User level:</td>
<td><input name="userlevel" type="text" value='
<?php
if($form->value("userlevel") == ""){
echo $req_user_info["userlevel"];
}else{
echo $form->value("userlevel");
}
?>' size="4" maxlength="10"></td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("userlevel"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="right">
<input type="hidden" name="subedit" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="usertoedit" value="<?php echo $usertoedit; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Edit Account">
</td>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this user, this cannot be undone?\n\n' + 'Click OK to continue or Cancel to Abort!')">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Does your server have short_tags enabled `<?`? Have you tried replacing them with normal `<?php` tags? Is your PHP being rendered? Does it have a .php extension?

Comment: j08691 yes i have tried

Comment: completely off topic, but do you really need a table for this at all? If this table is being used for positioning fields and captions in a login form (which is what it looks like), then it's not considered good practice to use tables for the layout any more.

Comment: No, I don't need it but I would at least like to have a nice form.

Comment: Where is your `$form`?

Comment: This page is an included page into another.

Comment: { I could also need help with another thing, but the error is contained within a page about 500+ lines }

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your syntax a little..

```
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($form->value("username")=="" ? $req_user_info["username"] : $form->value("username"))); ?>" size="56" maxlength="30"></td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("username"); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>New Password:</td>
<td><input name="newpass" type="password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($form->value("newpass")); ?>" size="56" maxlength="30"></td>
<td><?php echo $form->error("newpass"); ?></td>
</tr>
```

For additional php error logging, put this at the top of the page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

Comment: Wow, still no here this is what I keep getting [link](http://www.jstone-inc.bugs3.com/login/AR.php)

Comment: Ahhh.. I have a feeling there is a problem with your $form object... can you turn on php error logging on this page - see my edit above for the code

Comment: Is `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>` supposed to show the errors?

Comment: yes.. though looking back at your code, I'm very confused why there is a problem - if you have access to your server logs as well that could provide more help in pinning down what is going on

Comment: Also - are you able to share the whole of ar.php? It could provide further help in assisting you

Comment: Master101 - can you replace all copies of <? with <?php - especially making sure the one on this line too  (    <input name="username" type="text" value='<? )